# Overriding Price Model Doesn't Work

Tags: price, overrides

I wanted to Override this
`app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price.php`

First I created Module `MyModule_Catalog.xml` Under `etc/modules`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyModule_Catalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MyModule_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

and under `app/code/local/MyModule/Catalog/etc`
my `config.xml` file

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_type_price>MyModule_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price</product_type_price>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

and under `app/code/local/MyModule/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/`
my `Price.php` File

and I've tried overriding `_applyOptionsPrice()` function but it didn't work

Heres my `Price.php`:

```
<?php 

class MyModule_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price
{

    protected function _applyOptionsPrice($product, $qty, $finalPrice)
    {
        Mage::log("Hello", null, 'optionsLog4.log');

        if ($optionIds = $product->getCustomOption('option_ids')) {
            $basePrice = $finalPrice;
            foreach (explode(',', $optionIds->getValue()) as $optionId) {
                if ($option = $product->getOptionById($optionId)) {
                    $confItemOption = $product->getCustomOption('option_'.$option->getId());

                    $group = $option->groupFactory($option->getType())
                        ->setOption($option)
                        ->setConfigurationItemOption($confItemOption);
                    $finalPrice += $group->getOptionPrice($confItemOption->getValue(), $basePrice);
                }
            }
        }

        return $finalPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: change myModule folder name to MyModule

Comment: Don't forget to flush your caches as well.

Comment: @AmitBera yes Amit its Already in that format but i replaced for just representation here

Comment: i flushed the cach nothing worked

Comment: May be the reason is it is protected function that you are trying to override

Comment: @Pratikbhatt but i'll try to override any Public now

Comment: You can override protected methods perfectly, there's no problem there. You should always stick to the original visibility though...

Answer (score 2):

Please do the following changes in your `config.xml` file. You have forgotten to define your module models:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mymodule_catalog>
                <class>MyModule_Catalog_Model</class>
            </mymodule_catalog>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_type_price>MyModule_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price</product_type_price>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: IconDesign is myModule is the Module name

Comment: If IconDesign is your module name then please specify your namespace. and make the directory structure like app/code/local/namespaceName/IconDesign/ and place the Price.php file inside app/code/local/namespanceName/IconDesign/Model/Catalog/Product/Type/

Comment: @AhmedAborady, the problem is in defining your MyModule models. I'll update this answer to use MyModule

Answer (score 1):

### You main issue Module NameSpace.

Module NameSpace is not match with stucture

As per as magento system, `IconDesign_Catalog` should be  `MyModule_Catalog`.
According to magento, in `every  helper,model and controller all php classes` at
custom module should be start with `ModuleNameSpace_ModuleName` .

This class name  has been taken from Folders name. 
like:

IF Modules basic folder location is **app/code/local/ModuleNameSapce/ModuleName**.

Then the `Basic Classes on all php classes` is  `ModuleNameSapce_ModuleName`
In You

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
<modules>
    <MyModule_Catalog><!-- Should be   from  IconDesign_Catalog to  MyModule_Catalog -->
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
     </MyModule_Catalog>
</modules>
</config>
```

Comment: IconDesign is myModule is the Module name

Comment: And The Module is running already in admin system > configuration > advanced

Comment: I have updated your question to use MyModule everywhere in it's text consistently.

Comment: thats what already done

Comment: @AmitBera, the OP has tried to replace the original `IconDesign_Catalog` module name/name space with a dummy one `MyModule_Catalog` when placing his question here on Magento SE. He didn't do this on all places, so that's what has caused the confusion here... ;)

Comment: Yes right sorry for that 
but IconDesign is my NameSpace 
local/IconDesign/Model/Catalog